# How to remove Salesforce CRUD Delete Security Risk?

Tags: security-review, delete, crud, security-scanner

When I scanned my app yesterday, and it raised a bunch of `CRUD Delete` security issue. So, I added `isDeletable()` check to all the delete query, and scanned it again. Still, it showed the same security issue on the same queries. So, i googled a little bit and some of the results suggested to put `isAccessible()` check along with `isDeletable()`. So I did that and scanned. Still, scan raised the `CRUD Delete` issue. This is my final code:

```
if (Schema.sObjectType.PurchasedProduct__c.isAccessible() && Schema.sObjectType.PurchasedProduct__c.isDeletable()) {
     delete pProduct;
}
```

What is wrong with this code? Is there anything else I have to do remove the `CRUD Delete` security issue?

I am using [Checkmarx](https://security.secure.force.com/security/tools/forcecom/scanner) Scan.

Comment: Are you using a Checkmarx scan? Are you sure you deployed the updated code to the org you are scanning?

Comment: yes. i verified it. i am deploying the updated code.

Comment: And you are using Checkmarx? How are you running the scan?

Comment: (It would be a good idea to add these details to your question, by [editing](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/307898/edit) it)

Comment: I am using Checkmarx scan. https://security.secure.force.com/security/tools/forcecom/scanner

Comment: I assume this code is unpackaged on the org?

Comment: I also wonder if you are complying with the [scanning requirements](https://security.secure.force.com/security/tools/forcecom/scannerhelp) and that the additional scans are actually successfully executing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along with isAccessible () Try the below syntax

List myList = [Select Id,Name from myObject__c];
if(myObject__c.sObjectType.getDescribe().isDeletable()){
    delete myList;
 }

Comment: thanks. it worked